simple express proxy - client receives http response header twice
I have tried to implement a simple http proxy.
The express route /proxy/* should forward everything to a unix domain socket.
Problem im facing is, that the client/curl receive the http response header twice.
One from the proxy server, one from the proxy target (part of the body).
curl -v http://localhost:8080/proxy/
* processing: http://localhost:8080/proxy/
*   Trying [::1]:8080...
* connect to ::1 port 8080 failed: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080
> GET /proxy/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/8.2.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Date: Sun, 29 Sep 2024 22:49:48 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 30
ETag: W/"1e-HL4/BzTDxxZMLqCN2LK+rorlmRE"
Date: Sun, 29 Sep 2024 22:49:48 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

* transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
* Closing connection
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
{"hello":"From plugin server"}

As you can see in the curl output, the second http header response is part of the body, which is wrong.
The code is very simple.
Proxy server:
const express = require("express");
const {createConnection} = require("net");


const app = express();


app.all("/proxy/*", (req, res) => {

    const targetPath = req.url.replace(`/proxy/`, '/');
    const { method, httpVersion, headers } = req;

    const client = createConnection("/tmp/66e5934cead5404f0e23dfb1.sock", () => {

        client.write(`${method} ${targetPath} HTTP/${httpVersion}\r\n`);

        /*
        Object.entries(headers).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            client.write(`${key}: ${value}\r\n`);
        });
        */

        client.write(`\r\n\r\n`);

        client.pipe(res.socket);
        res.socket.pipe(client);

    });

    // simulate end
    // force end of request/response
    setTimeout(() => {
        res.socket.end();
    }, 3000);

});

app.listen(8080, "127.0.0.1", (err) => {
    console.log(err || "Listening for requests on 8080");
});

Proxy target, which listens on the domain socket:
const {createServer} = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const {tmpdir} = require("os");
const { rmSync } = require("fs");

const SOCKET_PATH = `${tmpdir()}/66e5934cead5404f0e23dfb1.sock`;

rmSync(SOCKET_PATH, {
    force: true
});

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);

app.use((req, res, next) => {

    console.log("Server hit", req.method, req.url);
    //req.pipe(process.stdout);
    next();

});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        hello: "From plugin server"
    });
});

server.listen(SOCKET_PATH, (err) => {
    console.log(err || "server listeing", SOCKET_PATH);
});

Where does the first response header in the curl come from?
I do not send any response in the express router handler to the client.
Everything is piped 1:1 to the domain socket, which i expect is the only part that sends a http response.
